# "Cannot verify or add the Internet Calendar in Outlook." while generating file on fly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outlook, icalendar

I have created an MVC application - calendar with option to generate .ics files on fly based on user's unique ID and send these files as response.

**Code:**

```
[RoutePrefix("iCalendar")]
public class OnlineCalendarController : Controller {
    [Route("{calendarId}")]
    public FileResult ReturnFile(string calendarId) {
        // code generating calendar file using iCalendar library
        return new fileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(calendarBytes), "text/calendar");
    }
}
```

user is provided link similar to this one:

> http://localhost:51756/iCalendar/userUniqueId

As long as user opens this link via browser file is generated and offered to download.

Problem I am facing is once user tries to add this link to Outlook it throws following error

**Error**

> Cannot verify or add the Internet Calendar in Outlook. Verify the
>   link is a valid calendar link:
>
> http://localhost:51756/iCalendar/userUniqueId

Is there any way, how to provide link that will **generate ics file on fly without saving the file in db or on server side** of application?

Comment: Make the request while using Fiddler and compare the headers to a request that does work. Perhaps the content-disposition throws Outlook off.

Comment: @CodeCaster Can you please explain me how exactly to do so?

Comment: [Download Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler), inspect the requests.

Comment: @CodeCaster Okey, I was able to capture file request and respons for browser, but I am not able to catch even request from outlook. Is they any way how to determinate, if outlook send request? Because it seems like it does not at all

Comment: Use `localhost.fiddler` to capture requests to localhost.

Comment: @CodeCaster Problem is not to capture request itself, problem is, to determinate if Outlook even send one

Comment: ... and in order to do so, you need to capture it. Use `http://localhost.fiddler:51756/iCalendar/userUniqueId`.

Comment: @CodeCaster That's exactly what i tried. In such case nothing happen at all. I also tried to save physical file on server. and open it via link: http://localhost:51756/iCalendar/iCalendar.ics. I can add this in outlook and everything works fine, but once i change it to: http://localhost.fiddler:51756/iCalendar/iCalendar.ics nothing happens. No error message, no warning, calendar is not added into outlook. Simply nothing...